# Undefined property: array to object conversion

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have this array which I intend to convert to an object for ease of use in my laravel blade but accessing the properties keeps throwing errors.

```js
$applicationDetail = (object) array([
      'completedApplication' => 3,
      'incompleteApplication' => 4,
      'totalApplication' => 5,
  ]);

dd($applicationDetail->completedApplication);
```

Running the code block gives the error:

```js
Undefined property: stdClass::$completedApplication
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what format in your array. It seems that the square brackets are not necessary. Try:

```
$applicationDetail = (object) array(
        'completedApplication' => 3,
        'incompleteApplication' => 4,
        'totalApplication' => 5,
    );
dd($applicationDetail->completedApplication);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it like

```
  $applicationDetail = (object) [
      'completedApplication' => 3,
      'incompleteApplication' => 4,
      'totalApplication' => 5,
  ];

dd($applicationDetail->completedApplication); // will give output 3
```

You are making a 2d Array, if you do

```
$applicationDetail = (object) array([
      'completedApplication' => 3,
      'incompleteApplication' => 4,
      'totalApplication' => 5,
  ]);
print_r($applicationDetail);
```

It will show the output

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [completedApplication] => 3
            [incompleteApplication] => 4
            [totalApplication] => 5
        )

)
```